# How to use GIT LFS to track iOS frameworks?

Tags: ios, git, git-lfs

I want to track my frameworks with lfs by a smart way. So this is my setting for git lfs:

```
*.framework/Versions/A (.gitattributes)
*/*.framework/Versions/A (.gitattributes)
*/{*.framework}/Versions/A (.gitattributes)
```

But it doesn't work. When I run

```
"git add ."
```

there's no files tracked by lfs.

How to fix that.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `git lfs track "*.framework"` or `git lfs track 'path/to/frameworks/**/*'`?

Comment: Did you try "git add *"?

Comment: @OrrMatarasso did my suggestion help?

Comment: @JAL I changed the approach for my problem, so I don't have chance to try your solution. Anyway, many thanks for your help. Hope someone find your solution helpful.

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3678

Answer (score 45):

Important: To successfully get Git LFS working, the file may not already be in your Git history.

Mandatory steps:

1. Install Git LFS via brew (or mac ports.. )

   `brew install git-lfs`
2. Initialize LFS inside jour local Git repo. Otherwise your commands will have no effect.

   `git lfs install`

`// Updated pre-push hook. Git LFS initialized.`

3. Do not track the iOS framework directly (eg. "opencv2.framework") because macOS will treat it as a folder. Just track the one large binary file inside the framework.

   `git lfs track MyProject/Libraries/opencv2.framework/Versions/A/opencv2`

`// Tracking MyProject/Libraries/opencv2.framework/Versions/A/opencv2`

4. Add all the files including the new generated ".gitattributes"

   `git add .`
5. Commit changes

   `git commit -m "added lfs binary"`
6. Now verify the file is properly tracked by LFS

   `git lfs ls-files`

`// 604bd36eb5 * MyProject/Libraries/opencv2.framework/Versions/A/opencv2`

7. Push the commit and see that Git is uploading the large file first

   `git push`

`// Git LFS: (1 of 1 files) 3.54 MB / 87.34 MB`

And you are done.

Comment: Good answer, but say I have a bunch of .framework, is there a way that I can find all large binary files in whose frameworks, instead of mannally do one-by-one?

Comment: Run this command in Linux to print out the top 250 largest files in your directory. Do a search for any .framework and add that to your .gitattributes manually with the full path.


'find . -type f -exec ls -alh {} \; | sort -hr -k5 | head -n 250'


MyProject/Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

Comment: Interestingly enough, this didn't work for me on a Mac.

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the next steps to add all frameworks to the git lfs:

```
brew install git-lfs                                 # install via homebrew
git lfs install                                      # initialize lfs for yor repo
git lfs track ios-app/Frameworks/*.framework/**/*    # track all frameworks in your project
git add --all                                        # stage
git commit -m "Added files to git lfs"               # commit
git lfs ls-files                                     # check that files are tracked
```

Eventually you should get the next result:

```
9ee501fdc8 * ios-app/Frameworks/Lottie.framework/Headers/Lottie-Swift.h
8fa3ecc835 * ios-app/Frameworks/Lottie.framework/Info.plist
4a870aa4cc * ios-app/Frameworks/Lottie.framework/Lottie
```

Take into account that this will not convert any pre-existing files to Git LFS (from other branches or in your prior commit history). To do that, use the [git lfs migrate](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn?utm_source=gitlfs_site&utm_medium=doc_man_migrate_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs) command:

```
git lfs migrate import --include='ios-app/Frameworks/*.framework/**/*' --everything
```

Comment: I had the similar issue adding XCFrameworks to LFS and using `*.xcframework/**/*` instead of just `*.xcframework` helped. Thanks!